# Чем объясняются задержки после запуска какой-либо Node.js-утилиты и увеличение скорости выполнения при повторных запусках?

Tags: node.js, npm

Эти два явления связанные, потому я объединил их в одни вопрос.

При первом запуске Node.js-утилит типа Gulp или Webpack происходит большая задержка до начала выполнения скрипта, да и само вермя выполнения относительно долгое. При повторном запуске уменьшается как задержка (практически исчезает), так и время выполнения скрипта. Подчеркну, что я **не имею ввиду инкрементальную пересборку**, какая например есть в Webpack - я имею ввиду **прерывание выполнения скрипта и ручной перезапуск** его из консоли.

Всё возвращается на исходные позиции после перезагрузки компьютера, ввода его в ждущий режим или просто если некоторое время не запускать подобные приведённые выше утилиты.

### Задержка после запуска скрипта на примере Gulp

После запуска gulp-а на некоторое время консоль подвисает и отображается только введённая команда:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее по прошествии некоторого времени (секунд 20-30) в консоли уже начинает появляться обратная связь от запущенного скрипта:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### О воспроизведении

Если я сделаю простой минимальный gulp-проект или webpack-проект и раздам его на GitHub, то он запустится и соберётся за считанные секунды, потому явление снижения время сборки при перезапуске Вы не пронаблюдаете. А дать доступ к реальному проекту, где много файлов, я как Вы понимаете не могу. Поэтому если приведённых ниже экспериментальных данных недостаточно для того, чтобы объяснить, что происходит, значит не судьба.

### Снижение время повторной сборки после ручного перезапуска

Ниже приведены экспериментальные данные сборки другого проекта. Сборка проекта тоже основана на Gulp, но там также есть и интегрированный Webpack, и компиляция TypeScript-а.

Основное время занимает сборка файла браузерного приложения `FrontEndEntryPoint.js` и серверной точки входа `BackEndEntryPoint.js`. При первом запуске всё это дело собирается порой аж минут 20, но при повторных запусках время сборки падает до порядка одной минуты.

#### День 1

##### Попытка 1 После включения компьютера

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **18 минут**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **841 секунда**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **405 секунд**

Значительный вклад в это время вносит описанное выше явление - какое-то время в консоли не отображается никакой обратной связи.

##### Попытка 2 Последующая

- Общее время сборки автоматического открытия в браузере: **55 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **44 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **22 секунды**

#### День 2

##### Попытка 1 После использования компьютера целый день

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **21 с половиной минуты**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **1074 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **519 секунд**

##### Попытка 2 Последующая

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **2 минуты 14 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **74 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **73 секунды**

В этот раз обе точки входа были собраны почти за одинаковое время, хотя обычно `BackEndEntryPoint` собирается в 2 раза быстрее `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`.

##### Попытка 3 Последующая

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **50 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **41 секунда**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **20 секунд**

##### Попытка 4 Последующая

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **56 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **43 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **22 секунды**

#### День 3

##### Попытка 1 После выхода компьютера из ждущего режима

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **24 минуты**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **1195 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **696 секунды**

##### Попытка 2 Последующая

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **2 минуты 45 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **72 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **68 секунды**

##### Попытка 3 Последующая

- Общее время сборки до автоматического открытия в браузере: **54 секунд**
- Сборка `FrontEndEntryPoint.js`: **43 секунды**
- Сборка `BackEndEntryPoint.js`: **22 секунды**

### Сведения о компьютере

Компьютер отнюдь не слабый (игровой ноутбук):

- Процессор: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H @ 2.20 GHz
- RAM: 16 GB

Никаких других проблем с быстродействием на нём не имеется.

### Вопрос

Можете ли Вы сказать, чем объясняются эти явления?

Я сам предполагаю, что первом запуске многие данные запускаемых скриптов кэшируются, потому повторные запуски проходят гораздо быстрее. Однако, если скрипты некоторое время не запускать, то кэш очищается, а потому время запуска и выполнения снова увеличивается.

Но это лишь моё предположение, так как на данный момент принципы работы кэширования в NodeJS мне абсолютно незнакомы.

Comment: @nörbörnën, я просто думал, что это насколько обычное явление, что оно не требует конкретного примера, но Ваша реакция означает, что это не так и что все обычные node-утилиты сразу же без задержек начинают своё выполнение в консоли. Я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: "все обычные node-утилиты сразу же без задержек начинают своё выполнение в консоли" я не вижу в моём комментарии такого утверждения, так что вы поняли меня не правильно.

Comment: @nörbörnën, тогда прошу прощения. Задам свой вопрос так: при запуске любого скрипта, который та или иная библиотека поставляет в папке `bin` с помощью node.js, что происходит перед тем, как скрипт, собственно, начнёт выполняться? На что тратится время?

Comment: 1. Я думаю что задержка во второй раз меньше из-за page cache. Сможете проверить на Линуске? Тогда перед вторым разом сделайте от root: `sync ; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. Если время +/- как в первый раз - значит точно page cache.

Comment: 2. Почему так долго? Надо смотреть системные вызовы. На линуксе посмотреть что делает `ls` можно так: `strace -to strace.log /bin/ls`, посмотрите как это работает. Для ноды соответственно `strace -to strace.log npm ...`. Лог будет с таймстемпами и очень большой. В нем и будет ответ "а что там происходит". Я думаю, сотни тысяч файлов обрабатываются, и поэтому так долго. Посмотреть сколько там их можно так `find -type f -name '*.js' | wc -l`

Comment: чисто из общих соображений, по-моему, дело в кеше. Т.е. `node.js` кеширует скомпиленный код проги. я знаю, что `npx` кеширует утилиты без их удаления (это я про подводные камни `node.js`, которых, по-моему, достаточно много), + в C# тоже JIT есть. может в этом дело и в этом направлении посмотреть стоит. такие оптимизации повсюду: начиная от процессора и заканчивая вашим языком высокого уровня.

Comment: @return, благодарю Вас за комментарий. Полагаю, Вы приблизились к ответу.

Comment: если не будет ответов нужно будет посмотреть source code `node.js`, а именно самой утилиты `node`. если вам кажется, что это будет бесплодно, то я таким образом нашёл вышеупомянутый баг про кешируемые пакеты `npx`. да, долго, зато после плодотворной работы вы будете довольны :)

Comment: ¿У вас на машине стоит SSD? ¿А антивирус включен? Картина обычного "холодного старта", когда в первый раз все работает медленно так как поднимается непосредственно с диска и проверяется антивирусом.

Comment: @user7860670, системный диск на SSD, но поскольку хранить документы на системном диске не очень безопасно, то все документы, в частности проекты - на HDD. Никакого дополнительного антивирусного ПО в добавок к встроенной защите Windows нет. " Картина обычного холодного старта" - это несомненно оказывает влияние, но через некоторое время скорость сборки снова упадёт, если какое-то время не собирать проект даже если не выключать компьютер. Так что какой-то кэш тут тоже замешан...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментариях выяснилось, что файлы обитают на ноутбучном HDD и на системе орудует антивирус. Соответственно тут возникает типичная ситуация холодного старта - пре первом обращении данные медленно поднимаются с диска и сканируются антивирусом. При последующих обращениях значительная часть данных уже будет в оперативной памяти, и уже проверенная. Соответственно рекомендации:

1. заменить hdd на ssd
2. отключить антивирус, или хотя бы добавить рабочие папки проектов в исключения
3. нарастить объем оперативной памяти, чтобы данные не так скоро вымывались из памяти

Comment: Вроде нормальные антивирусы сканируют файлы один раз и потом помнят, что уже просканировано?

Comment: Когда файл попадается повторно, то он по идее все равно должен быть проверен на аутентичность, как минимум.

Comment: Следование одной только Вашей первой рекомендации решило проблему. Честно говоря, я не знал, что разработчики должны де-факто хранить свои проекты на SSD, а компьютеры с HDD для разработки больше не годятся. Это важно иметь ввиду, когда начальник будет скупиться на хороший компьютер =)

Answer (score 3):

> **Этот ответ является предположением и может быть ошибочным**

node_modules - это куча мелких файлов, которые нужно прочитать прежде чем выполнять. Чтение с диска такой мелочёвки - штука довольно длительная. При повторном запуске надо прочитать те же самые файлы, но есть такая штука, как дисковый кэш, из которого их можно прочитать быстрее - вот и получается ускорение за счёт экономии на чтении скриптов.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! То, что Вы говорите, очень похоже на правду, потому что моя основанная на Gulp и Webpack утилита даже будучи собранной Webpack-ом подключает зависимости в ходе выполнения (за счёт WebpackNodeExternals). Видимо многочисленные gulp- и webpack-плагины, а также другие библиотеки - это и есть та самая куча мелких файлов, о которой Вы говорите.

Comment: Чтобы подтвердить или опровергнуть я бы попробовал запустить сборку с [ram диска](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software#Microsoft_Windows)-а. Если дело в дисковом кеше, то тут скорость будет одинаковая при любом запуске (и сравнимая с "быстрыми" случаями)

Comment: Я приношу свои извинения за то, что не могу присвоить награду сразу двум ответившим. Ваш ответ, как я уже сказал, вполне правдоподобен и потому заслуживает награды, но к сожалению, присвоить награду можно только одному участнику...